# install stalls for phantomjs2 on mac osx El Capitan

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to start using phantomjs2 and can't seem to install it.
I'm using the npm wrapper https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs2
[image]
and it stops here.

Comment: If it's installing globally (npm install -g) you need to prepend sudo to your npm install.

Comment: that has nothing to do with my question, and you should investigate how you can install global modules without sudo

Comment: The output does say 'Looks like an `npm install -g`;'.